# How can the story of Vishnu getting Sudarshana Chakra later be reconciled with Aniruddha holding the Chakra at the time of creation?

Tags: vishnu, weapon, sudarsana

Many scriptures describe how Lord Vishnu got the Sudarshan Chakra - some say that he got it from Shiva; while, other say he got it from Viswakarma.

Now, coming to the description of creation of the universe, when Vishnu manifested in the Anirudhha form; he had held in his four hands, the mace, lotus, shell and the chakra.

So, what is the authentic version of how he got the chakra? How can these stories be reconciled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the story of the "Sudarśana Chakra"?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2175/what-is-the-story-of-the-sudar%c5%9bana-chakra)

Comment: @Mr_Green This is not duplicate. OP wants reconciliation between two different stories of origin of Sudarshana chakra.

Comment: @TheDestroyer it seems the answer in the duplicate post explains everything.

Comment: @MrGreen it doesn't which is why I posted a comment in that answer

Comment: There are lots of Sudarshana Chakras; Para Vasudeva has one, and each of the four Vyuha forms have one.  (See my answer [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6923/36) for more information on the Vyuha forms.) So I think Vishwakarma just made one Sudarshana Chakra but Vishnu already had others.

Comment: @Keshav A better way to state that would be the same Sudarshana Chakra has many manifestations. Because Sudarshana is Chakratthazhvar, so there can not be many of him, there can be only many forms of the same deity.

Comment: @Mr_Green: Then what about the story of Shiva giving Sudarshan Chakra to Vishnu?