# Who is the ruler of Earth?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, lokas, indra, earth

For Brahma loka it is Brahma, for Vaikunta it is Lord Vishnu and for Kailash it is Lord Shiva, for Heaven it is Indra.

- In a similar way, who is the ruler of the Earth?
- Is it Lord Vishnu because Earth is wife of Lord Vishnu?

Actually Lord Vishnu is the ruler of the universe and Indra is his sub-ordinate.

- In a similar way, didn't Lord Vishnu appoint any sub-ordinates for the earth?

Comment: The ruler of the Earth in particular is Surya's son Vaivasvata Manu.

Comment: Humanity rules the Earth. Its only humans who are, by default, excluded from the scope of natural order (driven by Chaos) that works on all the other creatures. So its only us who can either maintain or disturb the balance here.

Comment: @Hindu I disagree with the distinction you make between humans and the rest of creation.  Don't you think that the behavior of both humans and non-human entities alike are driven by the divine?  Adi Shankaracharya says in teh Brahma Sutra Bhashya that "the Lord is a causal agent in all activity. "  http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe38/sbe38042.htm

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Indeed! But here we are solely taking about the physical "ruler" of Earth. My distinction is in physical realm only and not spiritual. BTW..I am NOT an _Advaitin_ :) I am JUST a Hindu (a relatively modern geographical term given to an _Arya_). And the so-defined "difference of thoughts, ways and beliefs", among Hindus, was propagated by the _Shudra_-minded Victorian Historians, who in fact, are the source of the JUNK called "sacred-text.com".

Comment: @Hindu If you want to talk about physical rulers, then I'd say that Vaivasvata Manu would be the physical ruler of the Earth.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan He WAS a human. Ain't he!? :)

Comment: @Hindu If he is a human, is he immortal?

Comment: @JavaTechnical Yes, he is immortal, or at least extremely long-lived.

Comment: Samrat's answer is right because Lord Shiva is everything. He had made Lord Vishnu and Brahma. All Gods and Goddesses took permission from Lord Shiva when they had to do something. When Lord Vishnu's two avatars Nara and Narayana pleased Shiva,they told him that Shiva is everything. Another reason that when the world was not there,Shiva had ordered Brahma to make the universe and ordered Vishnu to protect the world everytime. Why Lord Shiva had ordered? Because Lord Shiva is the main God and he is the ruler of the whole world.

Comment: Sage Kashyapa own earth. He received the earth obtained by Parashurama.

Comment: @JavaTechnical but kailash mountain is on earth :D

Answer (score 7):

The ruler of the Earth at any given time is known as the Manu, the father of mankind (the Manavas).  A Kalpa, or day of Brahma, is divided into 14 periods known as Manvantaras (consisting of about 71 Mahayugas each), and during each Manvantara a separate Manu rules.  [Here](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/11/chapter-view) is how the Srimad Bhagavatam describes it:

> After the end of Brahmā’s night, the creation of the three worlds begins again in the daytime of Brahmā, and they continue to exist through the life durations of fourteen consecutive Manus, or fathers of mankind.  Each and every Manu enjoys a life of a little more than seventy-one sets of four millenniums.  After the dissolution of each and every Manu, the next Manu comes in order, along with his descendants, who rule over the different [lands]; but the seven famous sages, and demigods like Indra and their followers, such as the Gandharvas, all appear simultaneously with Manu.

In [another chapter](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/13/chapter-view) of the Srimad Bhagavatam, Brahma tells Swayambhuva Manu, the first Manu of the present Kalpa, what his job is:

> Since you are my very obedient son, I ask you to beget children qualified like yourself in the womb of your wife. **Rule the world in pursuance of the principles of devotional service unto [Vishnu]**, and thus worship the Lord by performances of yajña.  O King, if you can **give proper protection to the living beings in the material world**, that will be the best service for me. When the Supreme Lord sees you to be a good protector of the conditioned souls, certainly the master of the senses will be very pleased with you.

We are currently living in the seventh Manvantara of the Shwetavaraha Kalpa, and our Manu is Surya's son Vaivasvata Manu, AKA Shraddhadeva, as [described](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/13/1) in the Srimad Bhagavatam:

> The present Manu, who is named Śrāddhadeva, is the son of Vivasvān, the predominating deity on the sun planet. Śrāddhadeva is the seventh Manu. Now please hear from me as I describe his sons.

By the way, Vaivasvata Manu is the son of Surya the son god and his wife Sanjana, whom I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/545/36).

Comment: Isn't Daksha Prajapati, the 1st ruler being sent to rule the earth and to continue growth and expansion on the earth.

Comment: Plz explain what one should infer from "daytime of Brahmā"? What brings a "day" for Brahmā? (e.g the Sun brings a day for us.)

Comment: @Hindu Time for Brahma passes slower than time for humans.  Brahma is awake for what is about 12 hours for him, which is 1000 Mahayugas for us.  The term "day" has no deeper significance than that - it's just an analogy because disregarding the time difference, he is awake for a period that is comparable in length to a day on earth, so we call it a day.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yeah, I live with that...Thanks pal.

Answer (score 2):

1. Kashyapa received the earth, obtained by Parashurama's conquest of King Kartavirya Arjuna and henceforth, earth came to be known as "Kashyapai".

[Sage Kshyapa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashyapa)

2. Earth or Bhumi (in cow form) is wife of lord Vishnu as per this sanskrit slok:

> समुद्र वसने देवी पर्वतस्तनमंडले। विष्णु पत्नी नमस्तुभ्यं पादस्पर्शं
>   क्षमस्व मे।।
>
> Smudra vasne devi parwat stan mandle| Vishnu patni namastubhyam
>   padsparsham shamashwme||

This make Lord Vishnu husband and he own define form of Earch