# Who is the first man or woman born in this yuga or in any other yuga?

Tags: yuga, kali-yuga, human

Regular process is mother will give birth to new baby.

Then who is the first man or woman born in this yuga or in any other yuga? How were those first persons born?

Were they born as babies or directly as adults?

**Edit**

this question is not duplicate as [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11660/do-hindus-believe-in-adam-and-eve-if-not-who-is-the-first-person-man-or-woman) , because i didt got solution for those first persons born as babies or adults ?

Comment: Oh man, It still remain as a Mystery. But Genetics Suggest Modern Female Came First (based on oldest Fossil we found till date) and fossil records suggest modern humans first appeared in Africa 1,50,000 years ago. According to Bible, Adam and Eve are the ancestors of all humans alive today. Good question, I say this one long back in Quora. Do you mind, if I ask you from where you got this?

Comment: It is said that Yama is the first human, that is why he became the king of death.

Comment: @CR241 Thanks for comment , Question came to my mind :)