# According to hindu religon who is the ultimate creator?

Tags: identification-request

According to hinduism , who is the ultimate creator ?

i.e who created the god ? then who created the thing which created god ? and so..

Thus who is the first creator ? And who created the first creator ?

Comment: Lord Shiva created Bramha and vishnu,

Comment: This is primarily opinion based question as different sects have different opinions.

Comment: @TheDestroyer how it is opinion based , according to Hinduism , who started universe ?

Comment: Related and probably a duplicate of [How were the trimurti born?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-were-the-trimurthi-born)

Comment: @AmruthA This is opinion based question as different people interpret Scriptures differently. Shaivites say Shiva created everything, Vaishnavites say Vishnu created everything and Advaitins consider both of them as equal and say creation is Maya. So, this generates many opinion based answers based on sects and generates debates.

Comment: See [How was the universe created?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8508/2995) - Hinduism has multiple creation stories one contradicting other. Also see [Do Hindus believe in Adam and Eve? If not, who is the first person (man or woman) in this world?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11660/2995)

Comment: Brahma(Creator), Vishnu(preserver) and Shiva(Destroyer) all are equally responsible for continuity of Life. If you will try to pick best among these three then you will ended up making your mind confused Because they all are equal where no one is bigger and no one is smaller.