# Why did surya not accept shani as his son?

Tags: surya, shani

Surya had three wives, Samjna, Rajni and Prabha. Surya and Samjna had two sons and a daughter. The eldest son was Vaivasvata Manu. And the remaining two offspring were twins named Yama and Yamuna.

However, Samjna delivers another son – Shani. As the children grow older, Samjna does everything in her power to distance him from Surya. Devoid of motherly love and fatherly attention, Shani is distraught, depressed, lazy and utterly directionless.

What was the reason that Shani's mother kept him away from his father? Was it because he did not accept him as his son like many say?

Comment: Shani was not the son of Surya's wife Sanjana.  He was the son of Chaya, Sanjana's shadow whom I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/545/36

Comment: This question seems to have come from the televisions serial on Shani Dev and has little scriptural basis.