# Was there an encounter between Ravana and Ikshvaku king Māndhātā?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, ravana

Many people know that Vishnu incarnated in the solar dynasty as Rama. But there is also another incarnation who is an ancestor to Rama, Mandhata (AKA Mandhatri). There is [already a question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7221/5212) about him in which his story of birth is also explained. Many scriptures like Mahabharata, Skanda Purana, Matsya Purana. Similarly, Bhagavata purana also describes his story. While explaining his deeds and greatness as an emperor, there is a shloka in [Bhagavatam Skandha 9, chapter 6](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/6/33-34):

> trasaddasyur itīndro ’ṅga
>   vidadhe nāma yasya vai
>   yasmāt trasanti hy udvignā
>   dasyavo rāvaṇādayaḥ [33]
>
> yauvanāśvo ’tha māndhātā
>    cakravarty avanīṁ prabhuḥ
>   sapta-dvīpavatīm ekaḥ
>    śaśāsācyuta-tejasā  [34]
>
> **Māndhātā, the son of Yuvanāśva, was the cause of fear for Rāvaṇa and other thieves and rogues who caused anxiety**. O King Parīkṣit, because they feared him, the son of Yuvanāśva was known as Trasaddasyu. This name was given by King Indra. By the mercy of the Supreme Personality of Godhead, the son of Yuvanāśva was so powerful that when he became emperor he ruled the entire world, consisting of seven islands, without any second ruler.

Here, it is said that Māndhātā was a cause of fear to many thieves including Rāvaṇa.

Was there an encounter between them like a meeting or a war where Māndhātā created fear in Rāvaṇa? Where is the story which caused fear in Rāvaṇa?

Comment: Why did u remove Ramayana tag? Most of the Ravana's conflict (be it with Kubera, Yama, Arnyak, Mandhata, Rama, Indra, Varuna, Bali, Arjuna........) found in Ramayana..

Comment: The question is not from the Ramayana or not about Ramayana.

Comment: Can someone please review and confirm what's wrong in using Ramayana tag in this Qn?..Most of the Ravana's conflict (be it with Kubera, Yama, Arnyak, Mandhata, Rama, Indra, Varuna, Bali, Arjuna........) are found in Ramayana..so I believe Ramayana should be the by default tag for Questions related to Ravana's conflicts...

Comment: No need to confirm and review. The questions should be tagged based on questions only. The question is not from Ramayana. It is precise tagging. Questions about Ravana should be tagged Ravana and not Ramayana. Questions can be tagged based on answers only when there is only one accepted answer which is possible on programming sites or bug related questions. It is not apt here. Questions tagging based on answers rests with the OP. That too when there is only one possible answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The story of encounter between Ravana and Ikshvaku king Māndhātā is present in  [this chapter of UTTARA KANDA of Valmiki Ramayana](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-26):

Ravana said:

> O foremost of Rishis, do thou tell me, who, of these kings going, if prayed for, may offer me the hospitality of a battle? For sooth thou art my father;do thou point out (such a man to me) O thou conversant with piety."

Being thus addressed, Parvata again said to Ravana:

> O great king, all these kings wish for heaven not for battle. I shall point out such a man, O great one, as shall enter into conflict with thee.
>
> There is a highly powerful king the lord of Seven islands, well known by the name of **Mandhata**; he shall enter into an encounter with thee."

Then there happened an encounter between Ravana and Mandhata:

> The Ten necked Rakshasa said to Mandhata: Do thou give me battle.
>
> Being thus addressed, Mandhata, laughing, said to the Ten necked Rakshasa If thy life is not dear unto thee, do thou fight with me, O Rakshasa. Hearing the words of Mandhata, Ravana said Ravana did not experience any affliction from Varuna Kubera or Yama; why should he experience fear from thee, who art a man?
>   Having said this, the lord of Rakshasas as if burning in fire, ordered the Rakshasas irrepressible in battle.
>
> Thereupon the ministers of the vicious souled Ravana, highly enraged and well skilled in warfare, began to make a downpour of arrows. Thereupon the highly powerful king Mandhata, with sharpened shafts, assailed Prahasta, Suka, Sarana, Mahodara, Virupaksha, Akampana and other foremost heroes. Prahasta covered the king with his arrows but before they had approached him, that foremost of men shattered them into pieces.
>
> Like unto fire burning down grass, the host of Rakshasas were burnt down by the king Mandhata by means of hundreds of Bhushundis, Vallas, Vindipalas and Tomaras. As Kartikeya, the son of fire, sundered the mount Krauncha with his shafts so Mandhata, enraged, pierced Prahasta with five Tomaras gifted with great velocity. Then hurling his mace again and again resembling that of Yama, he struck, vehemently, Ravana s car therewith.
>
> That club, resembling the lightning, vehemently descended (upon Ravana's car)and Ravana, like Sakra's banner, was speedily upset by that. Like unto the rising of the waters of the Salt ocean on the full moon, the king Mandhata s joy and strength were greatly increased. Thereupon the entire Rakshasa host, emitting loud cries, stood encircling on all sides the lord of Rakshasas.
>
> Thereat speedily regaining his sense, Ravana, a terror unto all people, the lord of Lanka, greatly assailed the person of Mandhata. And beholding thtt king in a swoon, the highly powerful night rangers were greatly delighted and emitted leonine roars. Regaining his sense in a moment the king of Ayodhya beheld his enemy worshipped by the courtiers and night rangers.
>
> He was instantly worked up with fire; and assuming a person resplendant like that of the sun and the moon he began to slay the Rakshasa host with a dreadful downpour of shafts. With his arrows and the noise thereof the entire Rakshasa army were overwhelmed like the agitated deep. Thereupon there arose a dreadful conflict between men and Rakshasas.
>
> And those two heroic, high souled and foremost of men and Rakshasas seated on warriors seats and holding bow and daggers entered (the field). And possessed by great anger they began to assail one another with shafts Mandhata Ravana and he again the king. They, being assailed by one another, were both wounded.

---

And here is the use of Divya Astras:

> [image]
>
> And setting the **Raudra shaft** upon his bow Ravana discharged it and Mandhata baffled it by means of his **Agneya (fiery) shaft**.
>
> Dasagriva took up the **Gandharva weapon** and the king Mandhata baffled it by means of his **VarunAstra**.
>
> Ravana then took up the **Brahmastra** stricking terror unto all. The king Mandhata took up the celestial **Pasupata** weapon, dreadful and increasing the fright of the three worlds, obtained by him from Rudra by virtue of his rigid penances.
>
> Seeing this all animals, mobile and immobile, were stricken with terror. Thereupon trembled all the three worlds consisting of mobile and immobile beings the Devas and all the Nagas became inert.

---

Finally the conflict was resolved by Pulastya and Galava:

> [image]
>
> Being apprised (of this conflict) by vitue of meditation the two foremost of ascetics Pulastya and Galava remonstrated with them in many a way and stopped the king Mandhata.

Comment: You should give chapter numbers instead of this, here. If it is split between many chapters, just say from chapter 26 to 28 like that.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Why so... See this answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11244/12304 by a Moderator and I hv seen lot of other answers here which simply say as per this chapter of so and so scripture...

Comment: If a moderator or many does, that is not right. https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12100/why-shouldnt-we-use-words-such-as-here-and-this-in-textlinks it gives no context on where you are going. Many questions and answers were written like with this and here. Now, the link is broken for many answers and the questions and answers are unclear..

Comment: @Sarvabhouma For Uttara Kanda, chapters are combined or splitted or removed (as part of interpolation)..Hence, chapter number differs a lot from source to source..Even if I give chapter number, there is high probability that it's number will be different in other sites/sources....

Comment: You can give the chapter numbers according to the version you have. Many claim interpolations but can't prove them. Giving chapter number gives context and where your link is taking them. This can be avoided if chapter number is there. There are related questions about this across the network. It improves usability.