# How did Sita marry Ram and Varuni marry Varuna?

Tags: vishnu, ramayana, rama, lakshmi, sita

Bhumidevi is the wife of Lord Vishnu. Her daughter is Sita. If this is so, how did Lord Vishnu/Rama marry his wife's daughter?

Lakshmi,who comes out of the ocean of milk,is considered the daughter of Varuna.Varuni ,who also comes out of the ocean of milk,can be considered the daughter of Varuna.Thus,how can Varuna marry his own daughter?

Comment: [Bhūmi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bh%C5%ABmi) is wife of *VarAha* avatar (which was in turn Vishnu). The time span among these avatars is huge. If you discard that, then many such ambiguous coupling can be found. e.g. Bhima and Hanuman were brothers due to being sons of *VAyu*, Sita and *NarakAsura* would be siblings, due to being born from *Bhumidevi*.

Comment: That is the beauty of avatara - the same God takes on different roles and relationships.

Comment: If you take Krsnavatara both Bhudevi as Satyabhama and Sridevi as Rukmini were Krsna's consorts.

Comment: Saraswati/Brahma (father/daughter) , Subhadra/Arjun (cousins) and many more such example present in Hinduism history.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Subhadra and Arjuna's marriage was fine. Subhadra is daughter of his maternal Uncle (Mama).

Comment: @AnilKumar In most of hindus marriage with cousins are not allowed. Even in my hometown, i have to skip the girl with my father and mothers gotra for marriage. Anyways there is one more example of Yama and yami and they were twins but that case was edge one and even got criticism

Comment: @AnkitSharma In south India, there's no problem marrying Mama's (mother's brother) daughter. Gotra of the girl changes after her marriage. So, there's no problem with marriage of Subadra and Arjuna. Yama and Yami are twins and that's not morally correct.

Comment: @AnilKumar related question [Are there any examples of incest in Hindu mythology?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7603/are-there-any-examples-of-incest-in-hindu-mythology)

Comment: @AnkitSharma i saw that question. But my point here is, marriage to mama's daughter is not considered as incest in South India.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Most of the time,Brahma and Saraswati are **not** considered father and dughter.

Comment: This quote : “In south India, there's no problem marrying Mama's (mother's brother) daughter.” <—— I’m not South Indian & I didn’t know this. This is very close bio relation cousin though ? Seven years late reply to say this doesn’t seem good from medical standpoint in having kids  Huge problems of genetic illnesses & such.

Comment: Bhumidevi didn't birth Mata Sita per se. Rather she was born in Earth if anything she is like an avatar of Bhumidevi.

Answer (score 0):

Name of varuNa's wife is gaurI as per mahAbhArata [anuShasana parva CLXV](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b130.htm) and [udyoga parva CXVII](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05117.htm) :

> *then the illustrious Sakra the lord of Sachi; and Yama with his spouse Dhumorna; and **Varuna with Gauri**; Kuvera the lord of
> treasures, with his spouse Riddhi;*
>
> *And the royal sage then sported with her, as Surya with Prabhavati, Agni with Swaha, Vasava with Sachi, Chandra with Rohini, Yama with
> Urmila, **Varuna with Gauri**, Kuvera with Riddhi, Narayana with
> Lakshmi, Sagara with Jahnavi, Rudra with Rudrani,*

vArunI is the daughter of varuNa and wife of sheSha as per [harivamsa Chapter 41](http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_041.html) :

> *sAsmi pUrNena yogena yaithavAmR^itamanthane | samIpaM preShitA **pitrA varuNena** tavAnagha ||2-41-21*
>
> *O one without sins! I am that one, fully suitable (to you) who was sent by **my father varuNa** to
> you during the days of churning for nectar (amR^ita).*
>
> *balaM jayasya daityAnAM baladeva divIshvara | ahaM te dayitA kAntA vAruNI samupasthitA ||2-41-17*
>
> *O the god of deva-s! baladeva
> (balarAma)! Let there be victory to you. You are the strength of
> deva-s against daitya-s. **I, vAruNI, your dear wife**, am standing
> near you.*