# If Goddess Sita is the daughter of Bhumi Devi, then how can we say Lord Ram is an Incarnation of Lord Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, rama, sita, bhumi

Lord Vishnu has 2 wives: one is Shree Mahalakshmi and the other is Bhumi Devi, as mentioned in the following shlok which many people say in the morning:

> ॥ विष्णुपत्नि नमस्तुभ्यं पादस्पर्शं क्षमस्वमे ॥
> meaning
> "|| O consort of Lord Vishnu, forgive me for stepping on you ||"

[Here](https://www.quora.com/How-many-wives-did-Lord-Vishnu-have-Is-Vaishno-devi-Vaishnavi-also-a-wife/answer/Sathish-K-Samy?srid=Ie9p) it is explained that Lord Vishnu has two wives, Sri Devi (श्री देवी) and BhooDevi (Earth Goddess)

If Goddess Sita is the daughter of Bhumi Devi then how can we say Lord Ram is Incarnation of Lord Vishnu?

If it is true, then in the form of Lord Vishnu, Bhumi Devi is his wife, and in the form of Lord Ram, Bhumi Devi is his mother in law.

Could somebody please explain this?

Comment: Related or possible duplicate of [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10686/how-did-sita-marry-ram-and-varuni-marry-varuna)

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani But I cant find answer for my question there

Comment: Lord Venkateswar​  (Vishnu)r has two Divine consorts Sridevi and Bhoodevi.

Comment: Yes there is no answer. That's why I have not voted to close.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64503/discussion-on-question-by-praveen-gaikwad-if-goddes-sita-is-daughter-of-bhumi-de).

Comment: Just like they say a father is reborn in the image of his son and so on so forth can be logically applied via a vis Bhudevi and Sita. This can be one opinion based rational way of looking at this situation. However, I'll really like to know what scriptures and Puranas say on this explicitly!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would like to make 2 things clear

### 1. Being addressed as a daughter vs being a daughter

In *Mahābhārata*:*Śāntīparva*:Chapter 50, it is stated that when *Paraśurāma* cleansed the earth of *kṣatriya*s, lawlessness reigned supreme & *Bhūdevī*, unable to bear the burden of sinners, started sinking down into the netherworlds. To save the cosmic order, the *ṛṣi Kaśyapa* held *Bhūdevī* on his right thigh & since the right thigh is reserved for daughters (the left thigh being for wives), *Bhūdevī* is also figuratively called as the daughter of *Kaśyapa*, hence one of her names is *Urvī* (She who is held on the thigh). Now *Bhagavāna Viṣṇu* had already blessed *Kaśyapa* by manifesting as his son in His *Vamana* form, so *Bhagavāna Viṣṇu* can also be  figuratively stated as a son of *Kaśyapa* (*Kaśyapa* did reincarnate as *Daśaratha* & *Vasudeva* after all).

So you can say - ***Bhūdevī* & *Bhagavāna Viṣṇu* can be considered as siblings, so is their union incestuous ?**

Obviously not, because *Bhūdevī* was not the actual biological daughter of *ṛṣī Kaśyapa*. And even before incarnating as *Vāmana* & *Paraśurāma*, *Bhagavāna Viṣṇu* had already made *Bhūdevī* His wife in His *Varāha* form.

This is my point - figurative speech shouldn't be taken in it's face value. In Bengali, fathers-in-law often address their daughters-in-law as *mā* (which means mother), but does it then imply that the union of that daughter-in-law with her husband is incestuous ?

### 2. *Sītā* as the daughter of *Bhūdevī*

This is a very big misconception. *Sītā devī* is figuratively called as the daughter of *Bhūdevī* because She was found there similar to how *Bhagavatī Lakṣmī* (who had actually manifested as the daughter of *ṛṣi Bhṛgu* & his wife *Khyātī* after the kicking fiasco) is figuratively called the daughter of the ocean - but as we know by now, figuratively speech shouldn't be taken in it's literal value.

**Then who are the actual parents of *Sītā* ?**

*Sītā devī*'s birth story is rather complicated. It is mentioned in detail in the *Adbhūta Rāmayaṇa*:Chapter 8. According to it, *Rāvaṇa*, desirous of subduing everyone & everything, was roaming around the cosmos, when he came across some *ṛṣi*s in *Daṇḍakāranya*. Not wishing to kill them, *Rāvaṇa* extracted their blood as a symbol of his dominance over them & his completion of the conquest of subduing the cosmos. As ordained by destiny, he stored the blood in a pot containing milk stored by *ṛṣi Gṛtsamada* for consumption of his wife who had obtained the boon of gaining *Bhagavātī Lakṣmī* as her daughter from *Bhagavāna Viṣṇu*. *Rāvaṇa* was unaware about it because *Gṛtsamada* was not  present in the spot at that time.

*Rāvaṇa* took the blood in that pot back to *Laṅkā* & lied to his wife *Mandodarī* (because *rākṣasa*s are described to enjoy drinking blood similar to how humans enjoy drinking alcohol) that the blood in that pot was as toxic as poison. Later that day, when *Mandodarī* found *Rāvaṇa* cheating on her by indulging in sex with the women from *deva*, *dānava*, *yakṣa* & *gandharva* families (whom he had supposedly kidnapped) in celebration of his conquest of the cosmos, she attempted to commit suicide out of grief by consuming the aforementioned blood as a substitute for poison. Instead, as ordained by destiny, *Bhagavatī Lakṣmī*, who was present in that milk, manifested into a corporeal form inside *Mandodarī*'s womb. *Rāvaṇa* was busy for an entire year enjoying sexual pleasures with the women he abducted, giving enough time for *Mandodarī* to nourish her pregnancy, & when the time came for delivery, she left *Laṅkā* in the name of pilgrimage, delivered her daughter, concealed her underground & left the spot. She was then found & subsequently raised by King *Janaka* of *Mithilā*, who named her *Sītā* after the furrough in which she was found.

**Why *Mandodarī* ?**

According to *Adbhūta Rāmayaṇa*, when *Rāvaṇa* sought the boon to conquer the cosmos, he didn't had any daughter, so he asked *Prajāpati Brahmā* that let his death occur if he harboured carnal desire towards his daughter. *Brahmā* granted this boon & destiny cruelly cheated *Rāvaṇa* by making *Sītā* born out of *Mandodarī*, making him her father by proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Hindu deities don't have DNA, this is an absurd question. Even if they did, Bhudevi is an aspect of Lakshmi along with Sridevi, so she is self-born in more ways than one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).